# AsciiDoc, how to have the Navigation bar expanded when opening the page?

Tags: asciidoc

AsciiDoc, how to have the Navigation bar expanded when opening the page?
The default Navigation bar on left side of an AsciiDoc page is collapsed when a user enters the page. This is good behavior for huge projects, however, for small and medium projects it would be beneficial for the overview to make use of nested lists and see the complete content from the beginning without clicking.

**The default navigation bar:**
[image: default Navigation bar]

**The navigation bar how I want it at startup:**
[image: expanded Navigation bar]